# How is the frequency of wlan -emitters changed in time?

Tags: network-manager, internet-radio

It seems that Ubuntu 11.10, specifically Network Manager, does not change at all the frequency of the wlan-signal.

Ok, if it does change somehow, then: **Which factors does the Network Manager take into account?**

**Does it take into account the humidity of the air?**

A few years ago the radio towers were made a lot more efficient by taking into an account the humidity of the air. It would be trivial to have humidity control measurers in my laptop either internally or preferably as an external body. It would definitely improve my internet connection's strength, since by increasing the signal frequency in the high humidity -conditions the frequency would be increased to the level that is allowed by the regional laws.

**Which files do control the frequency of the given emitters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather thought the frequency depended on the access point's channel. If we assume that is correct (it may well not be) to change dynamically, you would need to interface with your router and have it change things.

This would probably lose you your connection.

I wouldn't bother, to be honest. Pick whatever channel gives you the best signal and stick with it.

Comment: Assume that you hijacking. The channels of the emitters are set before so that you cannot affect to them. You need to be in the same channel as the station where you are getting the internet connection. **Is that right?**